# Authentication with Bearer Token goes to Home Controller instead of API Controller?

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4, bearer-token

I've got an Angular2 ASP Core 1.1 application that we are authenticating with Identity Server. We've got the user credentials set up through Identity server, but we also need to authenticate another server with a bearer token.

Here's my validation code. I can post more if I need to, but I'm sure my issue described below is in this snippet in the `OnTokenValidated` section. I think I'm not correctly returning the task?

```cs
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000/",
            AuthenticationScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            Audience = "ServerAPI",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            SaveToken = true,
            Events = new JwtBearerEvents() {
                OnTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    List<Claim> claims = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.ToList();
                    var userIdClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Subject);
                    // Find claim identity attached to principal.
                    var claimIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Ticket.Principal.Identity;

                    Claim claim = new Claim("admin", "Administrator");
                    claimIdentity.AddClaim(claim);
                    context.HttpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimIdentity);

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                OnAuthenticationFailed = (jwt) =>
                {
                    if (jwt.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && jwt.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                    {
                        jwt.Response.StatusCode = 403;

                        jwt.State = EventResultState.HandledResponse;
                        jwt.Response.Redirect(jwt.Request.Host.ToString());
                    }
                    return Task.FromException(jwt.Exception);
                }
            } 
        });
```

The token gets validated, but immediately after, it goes to my home controller, instead of the API controller? I could add the route into claims and redirect to the API from, but I feel pretty confident that isn't the correct way to do it.

What Am I missing for the `OnTokenValidated` event to get the code to continue on to the request URL?

And by the way, I am hitting my breakpoint on that event so the token is validated, and then immediately hits my index on the home controller

Comment: it looks like its redirecting to the default route, try adjusting the default root and it should work the way you are expecting

Comment: @PrashantLakhlani but I have multiple APIs so I don't want to set the default route to one API? Unless I am misunderstanding what you're saying? I want it to redirect to the route sent in the request after it validates the token

Comment: So you have an Angular2 Client that needs to use one or more other API's?

Comment: @aaronR I should have been more clear. The angular part is separate from this part of the application. We have an angular app nested in our home controller, but our other controllers house the API's. And I have an external server trying to access the API's with a bearer token